# Singular fiber of a family of elliptic curves with Kodaira's symbol mI_V

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_surface, one classifies all fibers of a minimal elliptic fibration via Kodaira's symbols:

$I_v$, $mI_v$, $II$, $III$, $IV$, $I_v^*$, $II^*$, $III^*$, $IV^*$

According Tate's algorithm [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_algorithm#:~:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20elliptic%20curves%2C%20Tate%27s%20algorithm,type%20of%20reduction%20at%20p%2C%20the%20local%20index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tate%27s_algorithm#:%7E:text=In%20the%20theory%20of%20elliptic%20curves%2C%20Tate%27s%20algorithm,type%20of%20reduction%20at%20p%2C%20the%20local%20index)  one can easily examples of fibers of minimal elliptic fibrations for all above symbols except $mI_V$.

Does $mI_V$ really appear? Is there an example for this?

Comment: There is a process called *Logarithmic Transformation* which, given an elliptic surface $X \to S$ with singular fiber of type $I_b$ over $s \in S$, produces an elliptic surface $X' \to S$ with singular fiber of type ${}_m I_b$ over $s$. See  *Compact Complex Surfaces* by Bart, Hulek, Peters and van de Ven, Chapter V.13 for this.

Comment: Thank your for your perfect answer!  Is there an analog of Logarithmic Transformation for family of abelian varieties with similar singular fiber?

Comment: Whenever you have a family of abelian varieties with an $m$-torsion section you can always pull back along the $m$th power map, resolve any singularities as desired, then quotient by the multilplication by an $m$th root of unity automorphism on the base composed with the translation by the $m$-torsion section automorphism of the fiber to produce a similar scenario.